# Django-jenkins --enable-coverage returns 'Coverage' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python-3.8, coverage.py, django-3.1, django-jenkins

I am using **django-jenkins v0.110.0** and **coverage v5.2.1** , with **Django v3.1**.
As mentioned in the subject, when I ran:

```
python manage.py jenkins --enable-coverage
```

I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'Coverage' object has no attribute 'data'

Below is the entire stack traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_jenkins/management/commands/jenkins.py", line 47, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_jenkins/management/commands/jenkins.py", line 116, in handle
    coverage.save(tested_locations, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_jenkins/tasks/with_coverage.py", line 29, in save
    self.coverage.stop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_jenkins/tasks/with_coverage.py", line 55, in get_morfs
    return [filename for filename in coverage.data.measured_files()
AttributeError: 'Coverage' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Test methods in tests.py were ran properly, and junit.xml was produced under the reports dir.
But no coverage reports, definitely, because of this error.
Am I missing something here? Should I specify a coverage configuration file (coverage.rc) for it to work? Is it not compatible with python3.8? Other issues?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a dependency problem. [django-jenkins](https://pypi.org/project/django-jenkins/) *latest* release was in september 2016. [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.0/) v3 was released in september 2019. You would have to downgrade django to a release from that period in time.

I strongly advice you to *not* solve this problem but rather select a different solution other than `django-jenkins`.

Personally, I use `tox` so I can deploy my testing and tooling on any ci/cd tooling combined with calling `coverage`/`pytest` and any and all tooling (`black`, `mypy`, `safety`, `flake8` etc) directly. Wrapper libraries such as django-jenkins are simply too unreliable or make features unaccessible due to wrapping. Take my [tox.ini](https://github.com/arbroen/gameoflife/blob/develop/tox.ini) if you need an advanced start.

Good luck.

Comment: thank you very much @Shine. greatly appreciate your answer

Answer (score 2):

This is late, but in case anyone else is facing this issue when using django-jenkins and coverage. I managed to get it working again by using coverage==4.3.4. I did this because from django-jenkins github I saw that they are using this version of coverage.